# How to pivot a dataframe with two columns with no index

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to pivot my current two column dataframe which currently looks like this:

```
one   two
 a    12
 b    32
 c    12
```

I want to pivot this resulting in neither column becoming the index. My expected result is:

```
 a   b   c 
12  32  12
```

a, b, and c are the new columns. 12, 32, 12 are the values in the row.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `set_index` to move column 'one' into the index, then use `T` to transpose.

```
a.set_index('one').T
```

Output:

```
one   a   b   c
two  12  32  12
```

Info:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 1 entries, two to two
Data columns (total 3 columns):
a    1 non-null int64
b    1 non-null int64
c    1 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(3)
memory usage: 28.0+ bytes
None
```

Comment: Doesn't work in a general case where column `one`  has  repeating entries, e.g. `a, b, c, a, b, c, a, b, c`.

Comment: @Confounded Why not?  Did you try?

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work, but it doesn't pivot the data frame - it just transposes it.    Try it yourself on `df = pd.DataFrame({'name': {0:'a', 1:'b', 2:'c', 3:'a', 4:'b', 5:'c'}, 'value': {0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4, 5:5}})`   The result should be a  dataframe with 3 columns `a, b, c` and 2 rows of values., but this is not what is returned by the proposed solution.

Comment: Actually it works for what it does.  If you want just three columns, then you'll need to groupby and aggregate then transpose.  How do you want to aggregate your values for A,B and C?

Comment: The original question asked to `pivot` the data, not just to transpose it.  There should be no aggregation of data, so for the dataframe in  my previous comment, the result should be a dataframe with two rows with values: `[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]`.

Comment: You can do this many ways here are two: `df.set_index(['name', df.groupby('name').cumcount()]).unstack()['value'].T` or `df.assign(row=df.groupby('name').cumcount()).pivot(index='row', columns='name', values='value')`.

Comment: Wow.  Rather convoluted for something seemingly so simple.  Surprised that there is no building way of doing this. like `unmelt` or something.

Answer (score 4):

If this is your input:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([("a", 12), ("b", 32), ("c", 12)], columns=["one", "two"])
  one  two
0   a   12
1   b   32
2   c   12
```

Then `a.transpose()` results in this:

```
      0   1   2
one   a   b   c
two  12  32  12
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: You can use `a.T` for short.

Answer (score 1):

Giving everything the same index with `.pivot_table`

```
df.pivot_table(columns='one', index=df.index//len(df), values='two').rename_axis(None, axis=1)

#or with pivot
df = df.pivot(columns='one', index=df.index//len(df)).rename_axis([None, None], axis=1)
df.columns = [y for _,y in df.columns]

    a   b   c
0  12  32  12
```